# How can I encrypt with AES in C# then decrypt it on Perl?

Tags: c#, perl, encryption, aes, rijndaelmanaged

Here is my C# code. How could I decrypt this in Perl? Or I cannot decypt it in Perl due to OpenSSL?

```
RijndaelManaged RijndaelAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
FileStream fStream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("11B2c3D4e5F6g7H8");
RijndaelAlg.IV = initVectorBytes;
string password = "11111111";
Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("22222222"));
RijndaelAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(RijndaelAlg.KeySize / 8);
fStream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
cStream = new CryptoStream(fStream, RijndaelAlg.CreateEncryptor(RijndaelAlg.Key, RijndaelAlg.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(cStream);
sWriter.Write(input);

sWriter.Close();
cStream.Close();
fStream.Close();
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Crypt::OpenSSL::AES.

Of course, your Perl code will need to get the right key somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Crypt::Rijndael](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-Rijndael/) if you use Rijndael/CBC. Or better describe your code.